# Jquery Mobile: Binding on "change" not excuted after redirect (rails 4)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.0.0rc1 with the gem 'jquery-mobile-rails'.
I'm trying to hide and show DOM elements on a select change, using the value of the changed select box. The code below works after the page was loaded initially.

Once I click on a put-request-link jquery mobile sends its AJAX-request. 
The request works fine, updating an item in the db and the updated item is displayed correctly on the page.

After the AJAX request comes back the on_change stops working. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function show_selected() {
    var selected_context_name = $('#context_description').val().replace(' ', '_');
    $('.' + selected_context_name).show();
  }

  function hide_unselected() {
    $('#context_description option').each(function(){
      $('.' + $(this).val().replace(' ', '_')).hide();
    });
  }

  $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    alert('INIT HIDING');
    hide_unselected();
    show_selected();

    $('#context_description').bind('change', function(){
      alert('CLICKED ON SELECT');
      hide_unselected();
      show_selected();
    });
  });
</script>
```

The link_to_method I'm using:

```
link_to(
  item.description,
  polymorphic_url(item, item_class => { done: !item.done? }, format: :mobile),
  options.merge({
    method: :put,
    'data-role' => 'button'
  })
)
```

Everytime I click on an update link, I get the alert 'INIT HIDING'. After an update the message 'CLICKED ON SELECT' is not shown anymore. So I think its safe to say that the binding does not work. I don't get an error message though.

I tried `$('#context_description').change(function(){` and `$('#context_description').on('change', function(){` with the same results. All methods work, but only on the first run.

**How do I get the binding right?**

I saw there's delegate as well and I was trying to bind the event to the document, but things are getting pretty confusing right now. I don't even know if this is about Rails or jquery mobile anymore.

P.S.:
The controller redirects back to the same path explicitly (not using :back) after every update. And I checked that the log shows: 'Started GET "/do.mobile"' initially and after the AJAX comes back with no params.

Edit:
I realized that the select-input had a different data-theme after updating an item. I forced it to use the same, but that didn't change anything. Maybe this sparks an idea for someone...

Edit:
After updating a form is added to the dom, using the url that was used for the update as an action parameter with the method 'post' (not 'put'). What is this sorcery?

Edit: And I found TWO whole elements with "data-role"=page including a select box for each and the whole content of the page. The first page element is set to `display: none;` The one select in there still works. The other does not, they have the same id, though. Maybe redirecting is wrong here?

Edit: I tried using a form instead of the link_to with put with and without setting remote: true explicitly... Nothing learned...

Comment: Is the `#context....` Added dynamically?

Comment: The button gets its id from <%= select :context, :description, ... %>. The items that are to be hidden get their class from the underlying model as well. So: yes, they're created dynamically. I checked the dom though. The assigned css-selectors are the same for the failing and the succesful call of the .change function.

Comment: Ok then try `$(document).on('change', '#context', function()`

Comment: Thanks! Now it picks up the change. It does not execute the hide correctly though because it picks up the value of the first instance of the #context_description select. Is there a way to find_by_id and use the last? I know you should only have one id, but somehow jquery mobile comes up with this copy of the whole page...

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your last comment :/ find what by id? Same id in previous page? Same code as above but selector `$.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]').find('#context').val();` to get the value.

Comment: YES! OMG! I can't believe it. It took the whole day. Thank you so much!!! I just had to use $.mobile.activePage.find('#context').val();

Comment: Are you going write an answer so I can accept and upvote it?

Comment: Great, that was easy lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To attach an event to a dynamically inserted items, use...

```
$(document).on('change', '.selector', function () { code });
```

To obtain value of a dynamic item by id (in your case)...

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('#id').val();
```